# How to optimize React components with React.memo and useCallback when callbacks are changing state in the parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've come accross a performance optimization issue that I feel could be fixed somehow but I'm not sure how.

Suppose I have a collection of objects that I want to be editable. The parent component contains all objects and renders a list with an editor component that shows the value and also allows to modify the objects.

A simplified example would be this :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Input = props => {

    const { value, onChange } = props

    handleChange = e => {
        onChange && onChange(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    )
}

const ObjectEditor = props => {
    const { object, onChange } = props

    return (
        <li>
            <Input value={object.name} onChange={onChange('name')} />
        </li>
    )
}

const Objects = props => {

    const { initialObjects } = props

    const [objects, setObjects] = useState(initialObjects)

    const handleObjectChange = id => key => value => {
        const newObjects = objects.map(obj => {
            if (obj.id === id) {
                return {
                    ...obj,
                    [key]: value
                }
            }
            return obj
        })
        setObjects(newObjects)
    }

    return (
        <ul>
            {
                objects.map(obj => (
                    <ObjectEditor key={obj.id} object={obj} onChange={handleObjectChange(obj.id)} />
                ))
            }
        </ul>
    )
}

export default Objects
```

So I could use `React.memo` so that when I edit the name of one object the others don't rerender. However, because of the `onChange` handler being recreated everytime in the parent component of `ObjectEditor`, all objects always render anyways.

I can't solve it by using `useCallback` on my handler since I would have to pass it my `objects` as a dependency, which is itself recreated everytime an object's name changes.

It seems to me like it is not necessary for all the objects that haven't changed to rerender anyway because the handler changed. And there should be a way to improve this.

Any ideas ?

I've seen in the React Sortly repo that they use `debounce` in combination with each object editor changing it's own state.
This allows only the edited component to change and rerender while someone is typing and updates the parent only once if no other change event comes up in a given delay.

```
handleChangeName = (e) => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value }, () => this.change());
  }

  change = debounce(() => {
    const { index, onChange } = this.props;
    const { name } = this.state;
    onChange(index, { name });
  }, 300);
```

This is the best solution I can see right now but since they use the `setState` callback function I haven't been able to figure out a way to make this work with hooks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the functional form of `setState`:

```
setState((prevState) => {
  // ACCESS prevState
  return someNewState;
});
```

You'll be able to access the current state value (prevState) while updating it.

Then way you can use the `useCallback` hook without the need of adding your state object to the dependency array. The `setState` function doesn't need to be in the dependency array, because it won't change accross renders.

Thus, you'll be able to use `React.memo` on the children, and only the ones that receive different props (shallow compare) will re-render.

**EXAMPLE IN SNIPPET BELOW**

```js
const InputField = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log('Rendering InputField '+ props.index + '...');
  return(
    <div>
      <input 
        type='text' 
        value={props.value}
        onChange={()=>
          props.handleChange(event.target.value,props.index)
        }
      />  
    </div>
  );
});

function App() {
  
  console.log('Rendering App...');
  
  const [inputValues,setInputValues] = React.useState(
    ['0','1','2']
  );
  
  const handleChange = React.useCallback((newValue,index)=>{
    setInputValues((prevState)=>{
      const aux = Array.from(prevState);
      aux[index] = newValue;
      return aux;
    });
  },[]);
  
  const inputItems = inputValues.map((item,index) => 
    <InputField 
      value={item}
      index={index}
      handleChange={handleChange}
    />
  );

  return(
    <div>
      {inputItems}
    </div>
  );
}



ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: `setState` is only available in class components right ? That will not work with hooks.

Comment: No, your `setObjects` is the `setState` of the `useState` hook. It's very similar. One of the few differences is that it replaces the `state` other than merging the properties. Because in classes the `state` is always an object, and in hooks it can be anything.

Comment: Hooks allow you to have state in functional components with a much clearer syntax.

Comment: @GeoffreyHug see the snippet I've added to the answer.

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood what you meant by `setState`, so if I understand correctly, you mean I can change my `handleObjectChange` by using that form so I don't have to pass `objects` into the dependency array and use the previous state instead ? I will try that

Comment: Yes it works neatly ! Thanks that's actually a simpler solution than mine

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it seems that `debounce` works if it's wrapped in `useCallback`
Not sure why it doesn't seem to be necessary to pass `newObject` as a dependency in the `updateParent` function though.

So to make this work I had to make the following changes :

First, `useCallback` in the parent and change it to take the whole object instead of being responsible for updating the keys.
Then update the `ObjectEditor` to have its own state and handle the change to the keys.
And wrap the `onChange` handler that will update the parent in the `debounce`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce'

const Input = props => {

    const { value, onChange } = props

    handleChange = e => {
        onChange && onChange(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    )
}

const ObjectEditor = React.memo(props => {
    const { initialObject, onChange } = props

    const [object, setObject] = useState(initialObject)

    const updateParent = useCallback(debounce((newObject) => {
        onChange(newObject)
    }, 500), [onChange])

    // synchronize the object if it's changed in the parent
    useEffect(() => {
        setObject(initialObject)
    }, [initialObject])

    const handleChange = key => value => {
        const newObject = {
            ...object,
            [key]: value
        }
        setObject(newObject)
        updateParent(newObject)
    }

    return (
        <li>
            <Input value={object.name} onChange={handleChange('name')} />
        </li>
    )
})

const Objects = props => {

    const { initialObjects } = props

    const [objects, setObjects] = useState(initialObjects)

    const handleObjectChange = useCallback(newObj => {
        const newObjects = objects.map(obj => {
            if (newObj.id === id) {
                return newObj
            }
            return obj
        })
        setObjects(newObjects)
    }, [objects])

    return (
        <ul>
            {
                objects.map(obj => (
                    <ObjectEditor key={obj.id} initialObject={obj} onChange={handleObjectChange} />
                ))
            }
        </ul>
    )
}

export default Objects
```